# Kafka does not retrieve messages which are sent when it is offline

Tags: apache-kafka

I have setup a kafka cluster on a machine and testing with kafka-console-producer.bat and kafka-console-producer.bat

I started zookeeper, kafka-server, and produce some test messages using kakfa-console-producer, followed by kakfa-console-consumer, no messages were printed.

However, if I start zookeeper, kakfa-server, kakfa-console-consumer and lastly, kakfa-console-producer and produce the test messages, the messages were printed out on the kakfa-console-consumer.

Why is it Kafka is unable to pickup messages when it is offline? I am only using 1 broker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka has a concept called consumer groups, every consumer when it connects to a broker joins one. For every consumer group, Kafka keeps track of the last message offset that was read. If a consumer group is unknown to the broker, a consumer parameter called *auto.offset.reset* influences what happens:

- earliest: start reading messages from the beginning of the topic
- latest: start reading from the current end of the topic (so any messages produces after the consumer was started)

The default for this parameter is *latest* and since the console consumer randomizes its consumer group, this is what will happen in your case and why you don't see any messages that were produced before the consumer was started.
You can add the parameter --from-beginning to your console consumer command which is used to control this behavior for this tool. Then you should see all messages.

**Update:**
If you want to ensure you pick up where your consumer left of, you will need to manually set a consumer group and keep this the same every time you call your consumer.
You can do this by creating a text file with this parameter and passing this in to your console consumer.

```
echo "group.id=test" > consumer.config
./kafka-console-consumer --topic test --new-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --consumer.config consumer.config
```

Comment: I do not want the messages which are consumed to be re-processed again. I am looking at consuming the messages which was sent when my consumer was offline.

Comment: Kafka by default retains offsets for 24 hours. The broker configuration `offsets.retention.minutes` controls the offsets retention period. If the consumer is offline and did not commit any new offsets in that period, then Kafka might delete the offsets for that consumer group.